# There is the presence of noise(High frequency) at simulation (post-synthesis and post-implementation)

Tags: verilog, simulation, xilinx, hdl, vivado

I am using verilog in VIVADO(XILINX) design tool, at **simulation**(post-synthesis and post-implementation) of my design i am getting a **noise**(*High frequency*-even greater then actual board clock) at near both edges of my derived(slow) clock. Can anyone tell me how to remove this unwanted noise.

the snapshot of simulation as follows:
[image]

The verilog code for this as follows:

```
module counter(
input clk,            //Actual clock(100Mhz ->Artix-7)
input rst,
output reg[7:0] out, 
output reg nc         //New clock(slow)     
);

reg [25:0]temp;
reg slow;

             initial
                       begin
                           temp=26'd0;
                           slow=1'b0;
                           out=0;
                       end

    always@(posedge clk)
        temp<=temp+1;
    always @(temp)
    begin
       if(temp==26'b10111110101111000010000000)//clock divided by 50Mhz
        slow<=slow+1;
     end

     always @(slow)
             begin
               nc<=slow;
             end 

    always @(posedge slow)
    begin
      if(rst==1'b1)
       out<=0;
    else 

       out<=out+1;
     end
 endmodule
```

Comment: You got code for us?

Comment: You likely have a combinational loop but could be other things like meta instability from setup/hold time violation. It is hard to say what is wrong or how to fix it without seeing the code.

Comment: I have added the verilog code above. Also, no negative slack(setup/hold timing violations) were present at the timing summary report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies with the following lines of code:

```
always @(temp)
begin
   if(temp==26'b10111110101111000010000000)//clock divided by 50Mhz
    slow<=slow+1;
 end
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
assign slow = (temp==...) ? slow + 1 : slow;
```

That will cause `slow` to be incremented asynchronously as fast as the simulation time step will allow once the `temp` value reaches your compare value.

In a combinational always block (i.e. on with no edge sensitivity), you should never assign variable `x` (or whatever the name) a value which is derived from `x` (e.g. `x <= x + 1`) as this is by definition a combinational loop.

Your logic for clock division is also flawed because you don't reset the value of `temp` to zero when the compare match occurs, meaning the division value is basically just the full range of a 26bit counter.

The following will work synchronously and reset `temp` at the correct time:

```
always@(posedge clk)
    if(temp==26'b10111110101111000001111111) begin //clock divided by 50Mhz
        slow<=slow+1;
        temp<=1'b0
    end else begin
        temp<=temp+1;
    end
end
```